# C++ Simple Converting from Binary to Decimal

Tags: c++, logic

I was trying to create a program that converts from decimal to binary and I'm having trouble. Take a look at what I have and give me a foot in the right direction, the program compiles but returns negative numbers. I'm debugging right now but as soon as the compiler hits the `num` variable, it pops up as a negative number.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int hexConvert(int* num, int Hexes[8]) {
    //int* Hexes[8] = &Hexes[8];
    int empty[8];
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        if(Hexes[i]-*num >= 0) {
            *num = (Hexes[i] - *num);
            empty[i] = 1;
        } else
            empty[i] = 0;
    }
    return empty[8];
}

int Hexes[8] = {128,64,32,16,8,4,2,1};

int main() {
    int num = 0;
    int here[8];
    here[8] = hexConvert(&num,&Hexes[8]);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        cout << here[i];
}
```

Comment: You should post it as codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: `int here[8];here[8]=something;` is UB.

Comment: Arrays in C++ don't work like that.

Comment: @MohitJain: Not UB, ill-formed.

Comment: Sorry about the edit-suggestion I unfortunately bulldozered by Hayden https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6617527. I re-applied the still relevant part manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) you can copy structs, unions etc but **can not** copy arrays directly. Becuase of this reason, you can not return an array and assign it to another array.

Instead of `somearr[8]` you can use `std::array` or `std::vector`. These stl containers can be copied and thus will solve your problem.

[Live Demo here](http://ideone.com/asUg9a)

Answer (score 1):

You're doing some things wrong.

1- I think you want to hold binaries in array for every decimal number. If you want to do this you must use 2d array. (e.g. decimals:[2,4,7] binaries:[[0,1,0],[1,0,0],[1,1,1])

2- You're using arrays in wrong way. If you want to send an array to function you must use like that:

```
// lets say this is a function takes an array
void foo(int ex[8]);
.
.
.
int main() {
int myArray[8];
.
.
//you must call it like that
foo(myArray);
//or
foo(&myArray[0]);
```

3- You're returning an int not int[]. Maybe you want to use an output parameter with your function that might help.

You must search and learn array usage in C++. Visit http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the function a pointer outside the array. Also, you are returning an element out of the array. An array of 8 elements has indexes from 0 to 7. Also, you can not pass an array as a function argument.
Read a tutorial on C++ and try again